# Connecting to different database dynamically in java springs

Tags: java, spring

I have created the Databse dropdown list using the JSP. If I select anyone of the database and it should be pointing to the database and then the query written should be executed to the database which I have selected.

Present work done.
Now I have created statically like how much database I have that much Properties are written in the property file and all the credentials will be taken by Context.xml so how can i create it dynamically so that I dont want to write the different properties for each database and i dont want to create the different session nor I don't want to restart the server when ever I select the DataBase ?

In the property file I have written the different properties for each and every databases and in XML also we have created the different sessions for each and every databases so i donit need to write the different sessions nor restart my Server after the selection of the Database

My question is to can we implement as per my requirement.??????

And another thing for the different database we have created the interface and for that interface we have created the implementation

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is nothing prohibit you from programmatically creating all DB related artifacts (e.g. Datasource, JdbcTemplate, EntityManager etc), and perform transaction management programmatically.  Of course you will be giving up a lot of facilities provided by the container (or, I should say, still achievable with high cost)

Another idea I believe will work (though I haven't tried) is to create a child application context from your main app context.  The child context will prepare/lookup datasource etc base on properties.  Your parent context will of course need to provide correct properties to the child context.  By doing so, it should be easy to leverage on feature provided by Spring.